# .addEventListener breaking code after being added as a for loop to apply to different elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working with this code:

```
var hexArray = ["hexa", "hexb", "hexc", "hexd", "hexe", "hexf", "hexg", "hexh", "hexi", "hexj", "hexk", "hexl", "hexm"];
var burnArray = ["burna", "burnb", "burnc", "burnd", "burne", "burnf", "burng", "burnh", "burni", "burnj", "burnk", "burnl", "burnm"];

function zip(a, b, f) {
    for(var i=0; i < hexArray.length; i++){
        f(a[i], b[i]);
    };
}

inita = function () {
    document.getElementById('hexa').className='wave';
};
initb = function () {
    document.getElementById('hexb').className='wave';
};

etc...

document.getElementById('hexa').addEventListener('animationend', inita, false);
document.getElementById('hexa').addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', inita, false);
document.getElementById('hexb').addEventListener('animationend', initb, false);
document.getElementById('hexb').addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', initb, false);
document.getElementById('hexc').addEventListener('animationend', initc, false);
document.getElementById('hexc').addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', initc, false);
document.getElementById('hexd').addEventListener('animationend', initd, false);
document.getElementById('hexd').addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', initd, false);

etc...

zip(hexArray, burnArray, function(x, y) { 
    document.getElementById(x).className = 'transtart ' + y;
});
```

And this works just fine. But to cut down my code Im trying to do this:

```
var hexArray = ["hexa", "hexb", "hexc", "hexd", "hexe", "hexf", "hexg", "hexh", "hexi", "hexj", "hexk", "hexl", "hexm"];
var burnArray = ["burna", "burnb", "burnc", "burnd", "burne", "burnf", "burng", "burnh", "burni", "burnj", "burnk", "burnl", "burnm"];
var initArray = ["inita", "initb", "initc", "initd", "inite", "initf", "initg", "inith", "initi", "initj", "initk", "initl", "initm"];

function zip(a, b, f) {
    for(var i=0; i < hexArray.length; i++){
        f(a[i], b[i]);
    };
}

inita = function () {
    document.getElementById('hexa').className='wave';
};
initb = function () {
    document.getElementById('hexb').className='wave';
};

etc ...

zip(hexArray, initArray, function(x, y){
    document.getElementById(x).addEventListener('animationend', y, false);
    document.getElementById(x).addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', y, false);
});

zip(hexArray, burnArray, function(x, y) { 
    document.getElementById(x).className = 'transtart ' + y;
});
```

And now the burnArray zip function doesnt spit out the output correctly and never fires the CSS animation I have set for it. Is there a reason that .addEventListener cant be set as a For Loop? Does it have something to do with the variables Im using? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it in your revised code in

```
zip(hexArray, initArray, function(x, y){
    document.getElementById(x).addEventListener('animationend', y, false);
    document.getElementById(x).addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', y, false);
});
```

y is a string not a variable.

However you want y to be a function object

place the following after you have set inita, initb etc noting that there are no quotes "

```
var initArray = [inita, initb, initc, initd, inite, initf, initg, inith, initi, initj, initk, initl, initm];
```

ie

```
inita = function () {
    document.getElementById('hexa').className='wave';
};
initb = function () {
    document.getElementById('hexb').className='wave';
};

etc ...

var initArray = [inita, initb, initc, initd, inite, initf, initg, inith, initi, initj, initk, initl, initm];
```

Comment: Oh man. Is it always some stupid oversight like that? Thank you very much!

Comment: @JSArrakis yes it is - I once spent two hours puzzling over code not working and not noticing I had hit the i rather than 1 in one section.